# Azure Data Disk upload and download using python

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

How can i interact with azure data disk from my python code to upload file to it

i am unable to find a solution on the official azure page

please can you add a link to the resource pages

Comment: https://www.mikaelsand.se/2019/11/simple-how-to-upload-a-file-to-azure-storage-using-rest-api/ this link helped solve the issue so posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot upload or download files to Azure Data Disk

Upload of files can be done during the creation of a new empty disk with the **ReadyToUpload** state

Instead, we can upload files to file share

You can use REST API to upload files to Azure File Storage

Comment: https://www.mikaelsand.se/2019/11/simple-how-to-upload-a-file-to-azure-storage-using-rest-api/          this link helped me so posting here